# Parsing file in linux : store timestamps only

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I have 31 files in one directory. 
File format is as below :

```
TimeStamop      user-id
1471417712595   1936f35c-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-49898523b8ea
1471417717238   e3153e8d-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-7710089c77bb
1471417718730   4e470320-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-29bc448f09a1
1471417719211   e8b6a6c0-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-dd68d836fb31
1471417723775   cbc009c1-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-88cda2b1b812
1471417723775   cbc009c1-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-88cda2b1b812
1471417725790   c332eba7-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-509c42a621d1
1471417725522   4712acf1-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-11a24bcbe7c8
1471417601920   502bc0dd-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-eff38b468461
1471417604615   8c6b2ef9-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-9efb1223e383
```

I just want timestamp information from it and want to write all the timestamps in one file using linux shell script. Total file size (31 files size) is of 4.5 GB.
I want efficient method for doing this task.
I have done this in python. but want it in shell script.

Comment: What format of timestamp is that ? It doesn't appear to be the usual 'seconds since 1970'. Converting it using the normal perl approach returns a year far, far into the future.  `$ perl -e 'print scalar localtime(1471417717238),"\n"'
Mon May 15 15:40:38 48597`.  gnu date also far into future `$ date -d @1471417712595
Mon May 15 14:23:15 UTC 48597`

Comment: this is timestamp in milliseconds. @steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`, from the directory containing the files:

```
awk 'FNR>1 {print $1}' * >output.txt
```

- `FNR>1` matches all records with record number greater than 1 from each file i.e. this is to get rid of the header from each file
- For those records, `{print $1}` prints the first field only which are the timestamps

Comment: `awk '$0^=1' * >output.txt` also works.

Comment: is there any way to unique all the timestamps and sort it ?

Comment: @KrunalParmar yes, do: `awk 'FNR>1 {print $1}' * | sort -u`